# How to populate a 2d char array with the alphabet

Tags: java, char, alphabet

My goal is to create a 2d array of the alphabet like this:

abc

bca

cab

Such that each row and column has all 26 letters.  I know I can do this the manual ugly way, but was hoping someone knows a more efficient way to populate the array.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: iterate a `char` from 'a' to 'z' in a `for` loop. Some extra code [here](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/java/source-code/java-program-print-alphabets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

```
class Alphabet {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    // Create an array that will hold the grid
    char alphGrid[][] = genArray();

    // Two for loops to print the grid on the screen
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<26; j++) {
            System.out.print(alphGrid[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

} // end of main

// Create a function to generate the grid
public static char[][] genArray(){
    char[][] arr = new char[26][26];

    // Two for loops to generate the grid
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 26; j++) {

            // Creates an int that will later be cast to a char
            int let = i + j;

            // Keeps the int from getting too big
            if(let >= 26)
                let = let - 26;

            // Add 65 to the int so that the char will return letters and not ASCII symbols
            let = let + 65;

            // Cast the int to a char
            char letter = (char)let;

            // Put the char into its respective place in the array
            arr[i][j] = letter;

        }
    }

    // Returns the grid
    return arr;
}
}
```

Output:

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
BCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA
CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZAB
DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC
EFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCD
FGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDE
GHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF
HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG
IJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGH
JKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHI
KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJ
LMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJK
MNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKL
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLM
OPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMN
PQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
QRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP
RSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ
STUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQR
TUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRS
UVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
VWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTU
WXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV
XYZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
YZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX
ZABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY
```

Answer (score 0):

I got something here! Not the best but maybe ull like it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Alphabet{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] c = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
        List<String> s = new ArrayList<>(9);

        for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i+=3){
            try{        
                s.add(""+c[i] + c[i + 1] + c[i + 2]);
            }catch(Exception e){

                try{        
                    s.add(""+c[i] + c[i + 1]);
                }catch(Exception e1){

                    try{        
                        s.add(""+c[i]);
                    }catch(Exception e2){

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println(s);

    }

}
```

Output: [abc, def, ghi, klm, nop, qrs, tuv, wxy, z]

Comment: It would be better to initialize the array in a `for` loop; for example: `char[] c = new char[26]; for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) c[letter-'a'] = letter;`

Comment: Like a counter from 1-26 just with letters insted of numbers?

Comment: Yes. It's a lot easier than hardcoding the array elements. Also you shouldn't catch `Exception` directly - specify the type of exception you want caught, such as `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.